# NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "abstract":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm coming back to an old 2.3.4 Rails app and I'm getting this error and not sure where to start. I also get this when I run a rake task. Here's the trace

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "abstract":String
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:268:in `=='
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `matching_specs'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `find_all'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:409:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:73:in `add_load_paths'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
~/Sites/Volunteer/app/config/environment.rb:7
~/Sites/Volunteer/app/config.ru:1:in `require'
~/Sites/Volunteer/app/config.ru:1
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `instance_eval'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `initialize'
~/Sites/Volunteer/app/config.ru:1:in `new'
~/Sites/Volunteer/app/config.ru:1
```

Any thoughts on where I should start to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Though it's not the same error, it may be related to an incompatible version of Rubygems. Try downgrading Rubygems or upgrading rails to 2.3.14.

[Gem dependency error in rails 2.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065523/gem-dependency-error-in-rails-2-3-4/5067951#5067951)