# Having Trouble Generating a Ruby Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I wanted to generate a new migration for a site running Rails 2.3.14 and Ruby 1.8.7.  I wrote the command

```
ruby script/generate migration AssetTable
```

Expecting the script to generate a file 20130522161112_asset_table.rb in the db/migrate directory.  But I don't see this file.  The output I get after running the above command is:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:81:in `add_load_paths':      undefined method `requirement' for #<Rails::GemDependency:0x7ffd183eba58> (NoMethodError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /var/www/pbcore/releases/20120416101734/config/environment.rb:17
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065523/gem-dependency-error-in-rails-2-3-4

Comment: So the issue is that I have Ruby 1.8.7 and I need to downgrade to an earlier version to make it work with Rails 2.3.14?

Comment: Hmm I just read a little bit of the post and I think you have to downgrade rubygems, not ruby

Comment: The answer says: "This is happening because you installed RubyGems that is too new for your version of Rails. Either downgrade (and re-run update_rubygems) or upgrade Rails to 2.3.11."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your rubygems versions, can you try to run:

```
$ gem install rubygems-update -v='1.4.2'
$ gem uninstall rubygems-update -v='1.5.0'
$ update_rubygems
```

Seen here: [Gem dependency error in rails 2.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065523/gem-dependency-error-in-rails-2-3-4) :

> This is happening because you installed RubyGems that is too new for
>   your version of Rails. Either downgrade (and re-run update_rubygems)
>   or upgrade Rails to 2.3.11.

Comment: OK I tried down grading to rubygems 1.3.5 but when I run `$ update_rubygems` I get `-bash: update_rubygems: command not found`

Comment: I'm beginning to think this has something to do with Paths, but not sure